# Backward compatibility of header height of NSTableView with OS X 10.11

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, osx-elcapitan

#### Background:

On OS X 10.11 El Capitan, the default header hight of NSTableView has grown.

#### Problem:

When I build my NSTableView on OS X El Capitan 10.11 (GM) and Xcode 7.0 (the stable one), the table header hight will be fixed with El Capitan's header hight even on the previous OS versions and so there is a strange unwanted space above the table header (see the screenshots below.)

[image: table header on El Capitan]

Fig. 1 **Table header on El Capitan** (correct)

[image: table header on El Capitan]

Fig. 2 **Table header on Yosemite** (incorrect)

This is of course an undesirable thing.

#### Question:

How can I avoid this? Is there someone who faces the same issue? I couldn't found even any article in which mentioned about this.

I put my NSTableView using the normal Interface Builder bundled to Xcode 7.0 with Auto Layout enabled.

#### Update:

I've just confirmed this issue was fixed on Xcode 7.2 + OS X 10.11.2. Now you can modify NSTableView on Interface Builder without worry.

Comment: FWIW, I had this problem on Xcode 7.3.1, so maybe it's back or not completely fixed.  I ended up just manually editing the xib (https://github.com/HermesApp/Hermes/commit/69df9493fc65119f2b7a629378cb8d06cdbfbb78).

Answer (score 2):

This definitely seems a bug in Apples framework. It only happens when a view is autolayouting. 
I managed to work around this by subclassing NSTableHeaderView like this:

```
class TGTableHeaderView: NSTableHeaderView {
    override var frame: NSRect {
        set {
            super.frame = newValue
        }
        get {
            var rv = super.frame
            if #available(OSX 10.11, *) {} else {
                // Correct in versions before El Capitan
                rv.size.height = 17
            }
            return rv
        }
    }
}
```

And then set this subclass to the header in IB.

Comment: Yes, this should be a bug. My work-around now is just re-autolayout them before the release build on my Yosemite environment. your subclass seems easier to manage. Thanx.  I hope the bug will be fixed by Apple soon.

Comment: If anyone comes across this, please file a bug report with Apple.